# Bridge Deal Scoring

Tags: code-golf, card-games

## Goal

Given a deal result from [Duplicate Contract Bridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contract_bridge), calculate the deal [score](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_scoring#Scoring_elements).

<sub>Basically the same as [iBug](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/71806/ibug)'s question, which was deleted. I figured out this scoring system while trying to answer that question.</sub>

#### Input

Input is a deal result, and whether or not the declaring side is vulnerable.

The **deal result** is a string in the following format:

```
[contract] [result]
```

The contract is defined as follows:

```
[tricks][suit][doubling]
```

- The `tricks` is a number `1-7` (both inclusive),
- The `suit`is one of `C`, `H`, `S`, `D`, or `NT` (Clubs, Hearts, Spades, Diamonds, and notrump)

  - Suits are grouped as follows: `notrump: NT`, `Major suits: H, S` and `Minor suits: C, D`.
- `doubling` can be *blank* , `X` or `XX` (Undoubled, Doubled, Redoubled)

`result` is the resulting number of 'tricks' in relation to the contract. The value can be in the range `[-13; +6]`, depending on the `value` (sign included).

The sum of `contract number` and `result` must be in the range`[-6; 7]`, which means:

- For `tricks= 1`, `result` must be `[-7; +6]`
- For `tricks= 2`, `result` must be `[-8; +5]`
- ..
- For `tricks= 7`, `result` must be `[-13; 0]`

**Examples of valid deal results:**

`1S 0`, `4NT -3`, `7NTXX -13`, `3HX +3`

---

**Vulnerability** can be input as a boolean or any *truthy/falsy* value.

#### Output

Output is the scoring of the deal result.

The score is based on the number of tricks in a deal, and whether it reached the contract.

---

## Scoring

The score is a measure of the result compared to the contract.

If the contract is made, the score for each such deal consists of:

- Contract points, assigned to each trick bid and made
- Overtrick points, assigned for each trick taken over the contracted number of tricks
- A slam bonus for a small slam or grand slam contract
- A doubling bonus
- A game bonus

If the contract is defeated, the defenders receive

- Penalty points, assigned for every undertrick (negative value of `result`)

---

#### Contract points:

Contract points are awarded for the tricks of the contract.

```
                                   Points per trick
Suit                      undoubled    doubled     redoubled
------------------------------------------------------------
 Notrump
  -first trick               40          80           160
  -subsequent tricks         30          60           120
 Major suits                 30          60           120
 Minor suits                 20          40           80
```

#### Overtrick points:

Overtrick points are awarded for the tricks made, more than the contract (`result` > `0`)

```
                                Points per trick
Suit                      vulnerable    not vulnerable
 If undoubled:
  Notrump                     30             30
  Major suits                 30             30
  Minor suits                 20             20
 Doubled (per trick)          200            100
 Redoubled (per trick)        400            200
```

#### Slam bonus

If a large contract is made, it earns a slam bonus:

- `tricks = 6` earns a bonus of `500` if not vulnerable, and `750` if vulnerable
- `tricks = 7` earns a bonus of `1000` if not vulnerable, and `1500` if vulnerable

#### Doubled or redoubled bonus

If a doubled or redoubled contract is made, a bonus is earned:

- `50` points for a doubled contract
- `100` points for a redoubled contract

#### Game bonus

A game bonus is awarded based on the contract points.

- Contract points below `100` earns a bonus of `50`points.
- Contract points `>= 100` earns a bonus of `300` if not vulnerable, and `500` if vulnerable

---

#### Penalty

Each undertrick (negative `result`) gives a penalty point.
No points are ganied for the contract, as it was failed.

```
                                      Points per undertrick
                           vulnerable                        not vulnerable
                   undoubled  doubled   redoubled     undoubled  doubled   redoubled
1st undertrick        100       200        400           100       100        200
2nd and 3rd, each     100       300        600           100       200        400
4th and subsequent    100       300        600           100       300        600
```

---

### Examples:

Deal result: `4DX +1`, Vulnerable=`true`:

- Contract points = `4*40 = 160`
- Overtrick points = `1*200 = 200`
- Slam bonus = no bonus
- (re)doubled bonus = `50`
- Game bonus = `500` (`140>=100`and vulnerable)

**Result =** `160+200+50+500 =` **`910`**

---

Deal result: `6NTXX 0`, Vulnerable=`false`:

- Contract points = `4*40 = 160`
- Overtrick points = `1*200 = 200`
- Slam bonus = no bonus
- (re)doubled bonus = `50`
- Game bonus = `500` (`140>=100`and vulnerable)

**Result =** `160+200+50+500 =` **`910`**

---

Deal result: `4SX -3`, Vulnerable=`false`:

- Penalty = `1*100 + 2*200 = 500`

**Result = `-500`**

---

Deal result: `7SNTXX -13`, Vulnerable=`true`:

- Penalty = `1*400 + 2*600 + 10*600 = 7600`

**Result = `-7600`**

---

## Example Input/Output:

Input is guaranteed to be valid.

```
1S 0 (non-vul)    # => 80
3NT +1 (non-vul)  # => 430
3NT +1 (vul)      # => 630
6CX +1 (vul)      # => 1740
4D -1 (vul)       # => -100
7NTXX -13 (vul)   # => -7600
```

---

Results can be checked against [these tables](http://rpbridge.net/cgi-bin/xsc1.pl).

I've also included a [TIO](https://tio.run/##xZffb9s2EMefp7@CRRBIspiCpH47VfcQZwgwoAGczNhg@CGNnTVAZQeyE7Qo1n89uztSpOzIqfcwFAYZ5UhR/PDuvjo9fN18Wi3V8339sGo2rFl488Ud@y144ms@5zWfhEOPXVXCY/d3rH4nhs1i89gsg@Dke30yCQdxJKPvk0F98yUQvI5UGA7mAykEWzUsFYN6EMhoEtLda3a/9M9GPizImmrq/TKdcXbEfoWLXPBScCmhxdBSaGCSpaAZEma8MqxgeN9YjGM99gTsiRA8UdASbUvxMfB/af7P8N52MIdNMzabPs3gAmAmQzK0HD@LIQOGDPacdRhkjJPi0lEouYdiXlWSQDocMJcraHFCR8PThJbnuV4DQWQBU6DF0BJoKbSsoGEESeD5KbQMWg6tyGkIOVJgzKDl0ApJZsRIAS2DlqdkIgpBx6UpyBVZTNdbDP2ukGb7qd42ehSWwi7ehojN5nNoZYGTHEWmd86lwE5hlzgQBCjRYdprDgUQeImekh0W3Ig0B0gOiXtYtD/Urj8UuD6BBvi8wDAQ2KFVJrGlSTOggFZm@GjsYuzAbHlgDwXuQ2CHHm6Dm3gw8BXei12sLE8h8BbslHBAeHAyLZxzyuxQ5yjDojmQTCKWQrvKHFFuSZANH8AVMqncMRUWBemUoNB1UKVhgbOHTklHpYlQAcDjDqvdiPVT9hKrVbKLqz4lK0yOJzpX4cy4BnMy8Nq4MtHbN4ZEpFepyTrZ0bIdG2kZ7kXIjpi1oz8Ws/8ZgyQrJdFAKXBytmMjp1CIJFlHzpT8D3KW0aM5hg4swjGYMp0sbaT16BUvcxtkqQnY3CRgGTs5A43KoOXQitJGl5EyXnQkQHV0gpyR5wfLmdl@b463EP1yBYnhQHK9ebgXu5heKY4FGUqjufb1QQqAaiawUx0ePENZZC5VkvxgSUvB/S8EBzZjMtUi9SoW5bpF2it5iFRQBmCHbyuZFDv5r4wIOCjcQaEclEoOdVJuWQgD0RRSKRyIpaPao1nwQnVYpaVBQEUx3OHSTJjvEhGV6oARE5YFcGHBFAZF6yECK5NeYasq/0OfrJV0WroEwSdKXSOovKMHr4yrttyKdRImsF6qOrLWYydZ27GRrOFehOrKmtona1fVVHD8KeEaamUOZwPzBsH8nQxfEY/@QgfrBSseuL1tGcA0suLhKhuUAywNWi926iAsJax4bFdNWjxMwjrxKA8Wjz1lDsd3uM00s3FddCnskEtmDqRb18C92KWOBRnwXcO1ziUOZ0uTXKKZ2HXqUR6uHntLHUoXywSPeCkAXHYK1a3axpQDmdguH7bkycnHbg3Vr4kmMQ@Rj1eqHZAPh1VYGgRUCKcSClPHtV3dgD4Iegc6/XipU04/uspk9QNf9iqVHf3okhk0/WnIgquomdaz0PPOLs7Pfq@@/eN5d/A5iFUT888uSGDQMEFDc7P8exEo/Mwk49wZYzKS9clZJS@0nQZqN1CcPJkBtmm@mis2rrofs9q4@HK7eNgMx5V/fTm69L0jsj4098sNw7n@n/4A5/snE386mcHf9z5nY30zQU3dmjycVWO9BK2gqZ/xM/ouGOkP6CP21@UfY3Z2OTpnF@fjc7CYw1rf1At2s2a3q6ZZ3G5gLixcjaZDNTudV6O3t6vH5SaADYWndQWrB6O364fP95sgnMpZePpEtqfQfp63TjiZrx4/TtVgHk1m06VzTs/un82zGXzle3gbRKU@UdJJnoqQW4OOKoGmKV3wGOIq0sOpoEKFbHqC2hksdwZ55iZQ1OZSG/WMZHc0t6Mzry9abFjB3tqIWnZjRyY6RsbVXeDnH66P1@zkeO4fB9rny5AzHSVN9eIIKXXHb6pmqEPF3AKHyMbcX39aPX6es4@Loc8bnLz4vF4MW8eyqJKepwPk5yXDVbXeNBAu0Tryr/1BoN/3YUQkkc/8CH6DoH4vYArMrEObRXfB1d78YVrMemJLD8GxNW@qcbuLHyYa4@zlcZoDdecJVccrCQkDRyYhjbfaFPN5u8bzvw) with all results hardcoded in python, to check against.

Comment: @PeterTaylor It is duplicate. I've edited that in, and updated the testcase

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), <s>211</s> <s>204</s> <s>195</s> 192 bytes

```javascript
(r,v,[,c,s,d,t]=r.match(/(.)(.T?)(X*)(.*)/),l=d.length,m=s>'D',g=(c*(m+=2)+!!s[1])<<l)=>10*(t<0?10*(l*(v?3*t+1:-"13"[~t]||3*t+4)||t):g+(10*l*-~v||m)*t+5*l+25*(c>5&&(5-c)*~-~v)+5*(g>9?4*v+6:1))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jdA7b4MwFAXgvb@iYUjutQ3BPFKV8hiaOUsZkBADMo@0MlCBy4T469RZOlRV1Okene9M96Ocy0mM75/K7Ieq3ppog5HNLGeCTaxiqohGqyuVuMIRLAQrTRAyogPBIzIZVZas@1ZdWRdN8eF8YG0EXSKIS3e7KedFIIiDYSgxirlNQIV2cruSwJy4RFEemAZ3jXxVxbLcCg@XRWHQUtA7Scx1XpaOOqjJJ5I6PgER@/s9@KZAsmpHDdDGz4lHZnoKOOImhn4aZG3JoYUGDP5GbYM9NqWcasSXh1/sXlLK/@Fq/PqLT6/ZPfbO5h19uqRZZuoP/Cy2bw) Link includes test cases. Edit: Saved 6 bytes by multiplying by 10 at the end. Saved 9 bytes thanks to @Arnauld. Explanation:

```javascript
(r,v
```

Input the result as a string and the vulnerability as a boolean (or 1/0).

```javascript
,[,c,s,d,t]=r.match(/(.)(.T?)(X*)(.*)/)
```

Split the string up into contract, suit, doubles and (over/under)tricks.

```javascript
,l=d.length
```

Count the number of doubles.

```javascript
,m=s>'D'
```

Track whether this is a major or minor suit.

```javascript
g=(c*(m+=2)+!!s[1])<<l
```

Calculate the contract score. This is 3 per major suit or 2 per minor suit trick, plus 1 extra for no trump, and then doubled or redoubled as appropriate.

```javascript
)=>10*
```

The score is always a multiple of 10. Subsequent comments take this multiplication into account.

```javascript
(t<0
```

Do we have undertricks?

```javascript
?10*
```

Undertricks are multiples of 100.

```javascript
(l*(v?3*t+1:-"13"[~t]||3*t+4)
```

If they're doubled, then the potentially redoubled score depending on the vulnerability or number of undertricks.

```javascript
||t)
```

But if they're not doubled, then just the number of undertricks.

```javascript
:g
```

If the contract is made, then we start with the contract score.

```javascript
+(10*l*-~v||m)*t
```

Add on overtricks; per trick, if doubled then 100 potentially redoubled and doubled again if vulnerable, otherwise 30 for major or 20 for minor suits.

```javascript
+5*l
```

Add on the potentially redoubled doubled game bonus.

```javascript
+25*(c>5&&(5-c)*~-~v)
```

Add on the slam bonus if applicable.

```javascript
+5*(g>9?4*v+6:1))
```

Add on the game bonus.

Comment: @Arnauld Oh, of course, `<<`, I knew I was overlooking something but I just couldn't think of it. (I rearranged your answer slightly for ease of explanation.)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>230</s> <s>225</s> <s>221</s> 220 bytes

I've posted this answer, as I found out the rules while creating this answer to the other question.

```python
def f(D,V):v,s=D[:2];d=D.count('X');m=int(D.split()[1]);v=int(v);C=3-(s<'E');P=(v*C+(s=='N'))*2**d;W=-~V;return[-~W*25*max(0,v-5)+P+m*[C,10*W,20*W][d]+5*d+[5,30+20*V][P>9],((m-W)*3+7+~-V*max(0,m+3))*d*10or+W*m*5][m<0]*10
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dc9Na8IwGAfw@z5FYIe8S9LYdrPGS7urCJO2EHIYqzJhUWlr2S5@9S6oGzm4HB7Cnx/Py/G7/zjso3FsNluwRQUr8WxgnS7MLLJZo4vJ@@G07xGsIc6c3vlvMemOn7seYSMtzoZLNuAs14qjbg5fPFxpNJCcok5ruIQYk4iQJqs0P5dZu@lP7d7wc0WimLi3LyTYwGNMV9QRkzMpSMUiX6xpLI1JQ03MlKA@Kq1ZLZ4tQ8jxChNFU3rm5a2Ho8oPaogUh5ZWxJHYGjcX1gfjsfVL@vOgfAUCMiAwuL1HoBfgSTz8CbVcAyoDcxFTdY/IkCQhSfL6DpHpNDDTAvCQXA2XIjDpcl3XPlO/C11NKv5DMkCJR@MP)

---

Saved:

- -4 bytes, thanks to Mr. Xcoder
- -1 byte, thanks to Jonathan Frech

Comment: [221?](https://tio.run/##dc/Pa8IwFAfw@/6KwA75LUnT1s0aL@2uIkxKIeQwVmXC0kpby3bxX@@CupGDy@WFL5/38nL8Hj7aJpqmercHe1SwEi9G1uvCLCKb1bqYvbenZkCwgjhz@uCvxaw/fh4GhI20OBsv2YizXCuO@iV88XCj0Uhyinqt4RpiTCJC6qzbDaeuMSiipU8S4t6@kGAjTzDdUEdMzqQg/Fyy6FKsqS1NSE1NwpSgPvTRZvVsGUKO@xGKxvTMy9scR5V/qCZStJ3vJo4k1rilsD6Zjp3f0v8PylcgIAMCg9t5BHoFnsTDn1DrLaAyMBcRq3tEhiQNSZpXd4icx4GJC8BDcjVcisDM19uq8pn6Xehq5uI/JAOUejT9AA)

Comment: Possible [220 bytes](https://tio.run/##dc9Na8IwGAfw@z5FYIe8S9LYdrPGS7urCJO2EHIYqzJhUWlr2S5@9S6oGzm4HB7Cnx/Py/G7/zjso3FsNluwRQUr8WxgnS7MLLJZo4vJ@@G07xGsIc6c3vlvMemOn7seYSMtzoZLNuAs14qjbg5fPFxpNJCcok5ruIQYk4iQJqs0P5dZu@lP7d7wc0WimLi3LyTYwGNMV9QRkzMpSMUiX6xpLI1JQ03MlKA@Kq1ZLZ4tQ8jxChNFU3rm5a2Ho8oPaogUh5ZWxJHYGjcX1gfjsfVL@vOgfAUCMiAwuL1HoBfgSTz8CbVcAyoDcxFTdY/IkCQhSfL6DpHpNDDTAvCQXA2XIjDpcl3XPlO/C11NKv5DMkCJR@MP).